# Scrollview and layout_constraintHeight_max making view disappear

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout composed of a `ScrollView` with a `ConstraintLayout` as a container. This container has some views and I want one of those views to have a maximum height, so I used `layout_constrainedHeight_max`, but then the view just disapear when lauching the app...

Here is my xml sample :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1500dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I simplified the xml to just reproduce the bug with minimum components. I tried many things but **imageView1** just keep disappearing and I don't understand why. `fillViewport` or `isScrollContainer` changed nothing and I am using version 1.1.3 of constraint-layout. ImageView1 will appear if the constraintlayout is not in a `ScrollView` or if I don't use `layout_constraintHeight_max` (android:maxHeight doesn't work) but the combination of both just doesn't work. So what am I missing ?

Comment: Hi @Kelly which one is ImageView1 as it seems the two of them are being called this way? Is the bottom image or the top one that is disappearing please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you maybe as a test add some width and height to the first image instead of using wrap content? Also is your second image supposed to be that big, 1500dp or it should be just 150dp? It seems too big and that may be why the other image is not being shown.

Comment: Hi @FrancislainyCampos sorry for the confusion I edited the post. I was talking about the top image, the one with app:layout_constraintHeight_max, the second is just here to have something to scroll (in fact it could be anytihng or several views it does not have influence on the first one). I tried a fixed height instead of wrap content like you suggested. ImageView1 does appear but at the height I fixed and app:layout_constraintHeight_max becomes useless which is not what I want sadly. Think of ImageView1 as an image which you don't know the size in advance but don't want to appear too big.

Comment: If you remove the second image the first image still disappears?

Comment: No the first image does appear. In fact as long as whatever is under the first image is not big enough to have to scroll the first image appear. So in this case it is the scrollview that becomes useless and that's why I'm starting to wonder if scrollview and constraintHeight_max are compatible.

Comment: @KellyRudy try setting layout height to `0dp` if you are using constraints.

Comment: @karan your comment saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that for `layout_constraintWidth_max` and `layout_constraintHeight_max` to work all constraints (left, right, top, bottom) needs to be set. It is not applicable to **imageView1** as a view at the top with variable height and other views relating to it.

I assume you want to make your **imageView1** have a maximum height of **20dp**. To achieve that try this code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Here changes are:

1. adding `android:maxHeight="20dp"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
2. removing `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="20dp"`

I would also advice you to set `layout_height` attribute of `ConstraintLayout` to `wrap_content` as `ScrollView` is assumed to contain a child that is bigger than itself.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and imageView1 does appear but strangely I can't scroll

Comment: I'm sorry, my initial solution was not correct. Take a look at my edited answer